# Where do I add App Icon for iPad Pro?

Tags: ipad, icons, xcode7, asset-catalog

From iOS Developer Library updated 2015-11-05:

*"With the exception of the App Store icon—which must be named iTunesArtwork—you can name your icons anything you want. Use image asset entries in your Xcode project for your app’s icon files. To add icons, assign the corresponding image files to the image assets of your project. At build time, Xcode adds the appropriate keys to your app’s Info.plist file and places the images in your app bundle. iOS chooses an icon based on whether its size is appropriate for the intended usage. To learn more about asset catalogs, see Asset Catalog Help."*

I'm using Xcode 7.1 and there are NO spaces for App Icons for iPad Pro. Someone said they were using the Xcode 7.2 beta and still NO iPad Pro information in asset catalog.

I read on this site to add **CFBundleIconFiles~ipad** in info.plist but that didn't work.

How do I add the 167x167 app icon for iPad PRO?

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 7.2 release now contains iPad Pro app icon with size of 83.5 x 83.5 points, @2x, which results in icon of size 167*167.

Comment: With Xcode 7.1, when I ran the iPad PRO simulator, the app icon scaled from iPad Air i'm assuming. If I submit my app for review with Xcode 7.1, and if it gets approved, would there be a scaled version of the app icon on iPad PRO devices as well or would the app icon be missing for the devices?